# Segue back to a navigation controller

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard

I am new to XCode/Swift and trying to storyboard my first Quizz app :)

I've read numerous threads of people who have faced the issue i'm facing, but I couldn't draw a parallel to my case. Would anyone know I could get this working ?

Here it goes (see the screenshot for more detail here)

[image: screenshot 1]

1) First comes a Tab bar. The storyboard I'm working on starts from 1st view

2) Then comes a navigation bar :

- On the 1st page, I can choose 1 theme (segue: show)
- On the 2nd page, I can choose 1 quizz (segue: show detail)
- On the 3rd page, I play the quizz - here, I just click on the end button, the code is not in this example (segue:show)
- On the 4th page, I get my result and I want to press "back" to go back on 1st page.

However, if I segue from 4th page to 1st, the navigation controllers "disappears".

[image: screenshot 2]

==> How can I properly segue back to my 1st page without losing the navigation controller ?

Thanks in advance for your support,

Regards,
Mathilde

Answer (score 1):

Connect your 'Back' button via IBAction to method inside your 4th view controller and then use navigation controller `popToViewController` method. Example:

```
@IBAction func backButtonTapped(_ button: UIButton) {
    if let firstViewController = self.navigationController?.viewControllers.first {
        self.navigationController?.popToViewController(firstViewController, animated: true)
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer. it sounds pretty straightforward, but when I run this piece of code, nothing happens while clicking on the back button.

Not sure what's going wrong. I'll keep you posted when I find it...

Here how it looks like in my code. My 1st VC is called "FirstViewController"

```
import UIKit

class endQuizA1ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBAction func back(_ sender: UIButton)
{
    if let FirstViewController = self.navigationController?.viewControllers.first {
        self.navigationController?.popToViewController(FirstViewController, animated: true)
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}
```

}